# CSS-HTML: Animation Delay Issue

Tags: html, css

Animation delay is not working. Used -webkit as well but still not working. Everything seems to be correct. I tried applying negative values but still did not work. I am trying to create google loading animation. Why is it not working? HTML is seems to be correct as. The delay should give a snake effect.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}


body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh
}

.dots-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  /*align-items: center;*/
  width: 700px;
  height: 100px
}

.dots-container .d{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: bouncyDots 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}


.dot1{
  background-color: yellow;
animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.dot2{
  background-color: purple;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.dot3{
  background-color: green;
  animation-delay: 0.7s
}
.dot4{
  background-color: red;
  animation-delay: 0.8s
}
.dot5{
  background-color: black;
  animation-delay: 1s
}

@keyframes bouncyDots{

  to{
    transform: translateY(3rem);
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
    <title>Training</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="dots-container">
          <div class="d dot1"></div>
          <div class="d dot2"></div>
          <div class="d dot3"></div>
          <div class="d dot4"></div>
          <div class="d dot5"></div>
      </div>
    <script type="module" src="training.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've correctly understood your question, the issue seems to be related to how you've attached the animation to the elements. In your current setup, the animation is applied to all the elements with the class .d simultaneously, leading to a synchronized start of the animation for all the dots.

To achieve the desired effect of having each dot begin their animation cycle at a different time, I would recommend invoking the animation separately for each dot. This way, you'll have more control over when each animation cycle begins. Here's a revised example of how you could set this up:

```
.dots-container .d {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  /* animation: bouncyDots 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate; */
}

.dot1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  animation: bouncyDots 3s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.dot2 {
  background-color: purple;
  animation: bouncyDots 3s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.dot3 {
  background-color: green;
  animation: bouncyDots 3s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.dot4 {
  background-color: red;
  animation: bouncyDots 3s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
.dot5 {
  background-color: black;
  animation: bouncyDots 3s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 1.8s;
}

@keyframes bouncyDots {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(3rem);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: This solved it. Thank you. My question, why didnt my original approach work? Your approach is essentially doing the same thing.

Comment: Hi @marsprogrammer. The problem you have faced was that when declaring a general class such as .d, will set all the sub-properties of animation in a single declaration.

Comment: It boils down to specificity. the .d and .dot1 have the same weight. (I personally would have expected the dot1 to override the .d because of cascading but perhaps someone could explain why that doesn't happen).Anyway, if you increase the specificity eg. by writing .d.dot1 etc then the delay is changed.

Comment: With animation you are actually using a shorthand for eight separate properties. One of these properties is animation-delay. That means, when you define a shorthand property, it assigns values to all of its longhand sub-properties. Any undefined sub-properties are automatically set to their initial values. In this case all dots have been set to 0s